# parse REGEXP in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a filter String containing something with

```
    ">53"
    "> 53"
    " >53"
    " >53 "
    ">53.21"
```

and extract the Double 53.21

**EDIT**

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s/^ *> *\\([0-9][.0-9]*\\) *$/\\1/p");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("filterValue");
    if (m.find()) {
         myVal = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    }
```

Riccardo

-- In unix I did

```
    echo '> 53.21  ' | sed -n 's/^ *> *\([0-9][.0-9]*\) *$/\1/p'
```

Comment: See the Pattern class.

Comment: Thanks, add the code. The problem still remains

Comment: That is because your pattern is invalid for the Java regex implementation. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't capture any group in your regex. For `sed` try with adding `()` around the `[0-9][.0-9]*` like `\(([0-9][.0-9]*)\)`

In Java the pattern should be the below one. You have few invalid characters at the end of your regex. May be for copying from `sed`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s/^[ ]*>[ ]*\\(([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)\\)[ ]*$");
```